# Double primary key in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, primary-key

I have Database first MVC4 application using entity framework application. One of My table has a compound primary key comprised of two of the entity properties. I have a MVC controller which handles simple CRUD activity. Entering data through this controller works fine.
However is throws an exception when I try to edit existing data.

```
"The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity"
```

The "edit(int id = 0)" method in the controller only takes one parameter so I need to be able to pass another parameter so that it can find the right data record. Can someone please help me and explain me how I might to such a thing.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to edit a record that has a compound primary key, then you need the values of all columns that are needed to identify the primary key of the record.

Your action method would therefore need to take in both values (assuming two)

```
public ActionResult Edit(int idField1, int idField2, string newValue) {
  // logic to identify object using idFields, apply new value and save
}
```

You should also be able to use model binding in MVC (assuming an object of type `MyObject`):

```
public ActionResult Edit(MyObject obj) {
  // logic to identify object using idFields in obj, apply new value and save
}
```

In either case, all of the id values that are included in the compound key need to be supplied to the action. The same would apply for a `Detail` method that is designed to return one unique object.